# Can't open Neo4j browser after loading the newest db dump

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Button which used to be blue and clickable is not clickable now:

[image]

In addition I can't launch the browser from context menu on the left (nothing happens):[image]

Comment: Update browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to update the browser